# Angularjs, storage data and scaffolding

Tags: angularjs, database, scaffolding

Some one can help me with some angularjs world doubts ?

Is there a scaffolding tool for angularjs? What is a good tool to storage data? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

For AngularJS scaffolding you can use Telosys Tools a simple code generator
using an existing database to generate CRUD screens.

See the tutorial for Angular JS : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/angularjs

and the tool web site : http://www.telosys.org/

You can store your data in any kind of database and expose a REST API to serve the front-end. You can also generate the service layer with REST services ( Spring MVC or Jax-RS )